# Should a PC's DNS Name be resolvable in an active directory domain?

Tags: active-directory

I have a computer joined to an active directory domain, abc.example.com.  The computer's name is my-pc.  When viewing the computer properties from the dsa.msc gui, it says the 'DNS Name' is my-pc.abc.example.com.  I assumed it should then be resolvable from another computer joined to the domain but its not.  Could I be doing something wrong?  Or is this normal behavior?

Comment: The computer is only assigned an IP address when it's online. Is that PC actually online?

Comment: Yes, it is online.